# Postgres query plan different on local and prod. Not using index and bad row estimation

Tags: postgresql, index, execution-plan

Confusing index-use question, I have a database that looks like this:

```
+-----------------+------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------+
| Column          | Type             | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description |
|-----------------+------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------|
| line            | text             |  not null | extended | <null>       | <null>      |
| elo_range       | text             |  not null | extended | <null>       | <null>      |
| white_wins      | integer          |  not null | plain    | <null>       | <null>      |
| black_wins      | integer          |  not null | plain    | <null>       | <null>      |
| draws           | integer          |  not null | plain    | <null>       | <null>      |
| games           | integer          |  not null | plain    | <null>       | <null>      |
| white_incidence | double precision |  not null | plain    | <null>       | <null>      |
| black_incidence | double precision |  not null | plain    | <null>       | <null>      |
+-----------------+------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------+
Indexes:
    "pk_opening_lines_v3_meta" PRIMARY KEY, btree (line, elo_range)
    "idx_opening_lines_v3_meta_line" hash (line)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_opening_line_v3" FOREIGN KEY (line) REFERENCES opening_lines_v3(line)
Has OIDs: no
```

And I have a very straight-forward query that just searches for specific lines:

```
SELECT *
FROM "opening_lines_v3_meta" 
WHERE line IN 
  (
    '1.e4 e5 2.c3 d5 3.b4', 
    '1.e4 e5 2.c3 d5 3.Qh5', 
    '1.e4 e5 2.c3 d5 3.c4', 
    '1.e4 e5 2.c3 d5 3.d3'
    -- ...
  )
```

Locally, I get a reasonable plan, which uses the `idx_opening_lines_v3_meta_line` index, the one I'd expect: https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/ARG#plan/node/3

But on prod, I get a different plan, where for some reason the compound primary index is used, and postgres drastically over-estimates the # of rows (estimated 1m, real 30k): https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/D2HD#plan/node/1

Local and prod database are the same. Same indexes, same # of rows, etc.

I've tried a `VACUUM ANALYZE`, not sure what else to try here. VACUUM FULL? Would rather not lock the db if I can help it, esp. since the docs seem to suggest this is only helpful when there's a bunch of unused space, which doesn't seem to be the case here.

Here's the plan in text format:

```
QUERY PLAN
Index Scan using pk_opening_lines_v3_meta on public.opening_lines_v3_meta  (cost=0.70..114347.06 rows=118076 width=96) (actual time=143.255..4409.818 rows=30274 loops=1)
  Output: line, elo_range, white_wins, black_wins, draws, games, white_incidence, black_incidence
  Index Cond: (opening_lines_v3_meta.line = ANY ('{"OMITTED"}'::text[]))
  Buffers: shared hit=35081 read=8486
Query Identifier: 5159034391756592230
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=206 read=12
Planning Time: 14.126 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 2
  Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 0.189 ms, Inlining 0.000 ms, Optimization 0.000 ms, Emission 0.000 ms, Total 0.189 ms
Execution Time: 4465.422 ms
```

Comment: I suspect the primary factor is a difference in either hardware, or cache warmth. (Note that the row estimate is even worse on the local system).  If you immediately repeat the identical query on each system, is it faster the 2nd time?

Comment: You should track_io_timing on on both systems, to get a report (inside the execution plans) of how much time was spent reading the blocks.

Comment: Gotcha, I just uploaded the text format of the plan. Unfortunately I can't track_io_timing since the prod database is managed by digital ocean

Comment: You could just drop the hash index on the non-prod system and see what happens.  I suspect it won't make much difference.  You could also see what happens after setting enable_bitmapscan off on non-prod, and setting enable_indexscan off on prod.  But testing those don't make much sense unless you find the timings are reproducible (i.e. don't get faster with repeat back to back execution) as things currently stand.